# How to write documentation for independent utility functions/scripts and have them appear in ./docs/modules.html?

Tags: node.js, typescript, typedoc

I'm learning to use [TypeDoc](https://typedoc.org/) (version 0.22.12) to write documentation in my *typescript*/*node.js* project.

I organized my project such that I have a *utilities* folder with one `.ts` file per one utility function.

```
.
│   package.json
│   tsconfig.json
│
└───src
    │   index.ts
    │
    └───utils
            addNumbers.ts
            subNumbers.ts
```

`addNumbers.ts` contents, for example:

```js
// addNumbers.ts
export function addNumbers(a: number, b: number): number { 
    return a + b; 
}
```

Likewise, `subNumbers.ts`:

```js
// subNumbers.ts
export function subNumbers(a: number, b: number): number { 
    return a - b; 
}
```

I want to document each function, for example using TypeDoc's `@param` and `@returns`.

So I write:

```js
// addNumbers.ts
/**
 * Function to add two numbers
 * @param a the first number
 * @param b the second number
 * @returns number equal to the addition of a and b
 */
export function addNumbers(a: number, b: number): number { 
    return a + b; 
}
```

Then, when I execute

```sh
npx typedoc --out docs
```

I get

> Info: Documentation generated at ./docs

So I go to `./docs/modules.html`, right-click and then *open with live server* (VSCode), and I get a webpage with nothing under **Exports** section.

What am I doing wrong?

---

It may be worth noting that I added the following to my `tsconfig.json` file:

```json
"typedocOptions": {
  "entryPoints": ["src/index.ts"],
  "out": "docs"
}
```

I'm not sure whether the problem lies in that `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: What's in your index.ts? TypeDoc documents what you export from your entry point(s) so if you don't re-export the functions from utilities, they won't show up.

Comment: @Gerrit0, thanks. My `index.ts` includes an `express` app with HTTP methods for routing. If I understand you correctly, my entry point needs to specify all files in `utils` folder?

Comment: Yes, or alternatively you could also give TypeDoc multiple entry points (possibly just src, with --entryPointStrategy Expand). There's a plugin to fake "lifting" exports up from all real modules into the global namespace if you don't like how that looks

Comment: @Gerrit0, thanks -- It works with adding `"entryPointStrategy": "Expand"` to `tsconfig.json`. However, I wonder which plug-in you are referring to. Is it [@rollup/plugin-typescript](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/typescript#rollupplugin-typescript), or something else?

Comment: I was referring to [typedoc-plugin-merge-modules](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typedoc-plugin-merge-modules)